# Getting Google Places API key for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, google-places-api, eclipse-adt

Over the Past week i have been trying to Implement Google Places API for android , Google's developer page says that i need a api key and after researching many forums I got confused as to what key should I be using I tried using the Browser key, the Server Key and also the android Key, nothing seems to be working for me, I have already been able to use The Google Maps API v2 using the android key, but i am really confused, can someone help me out? The Webpages that i have been referring to are :
First [Link][1]
and Second [Link](http://javapapers.com/android/find-places-nearby-in-google-maps-using-google-places-apiandroid-app/)

Please help me out ,also I am trying to develop the android app using Eclipse and ADT so some of the latest forums become obsolete for me, and since Google keeps changing the layout of their developer console its hard to keep a track of the older Guides Provided here
Thank You

This is what I have Done
[As you can see I have enabled Places API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqdcj.jpg)
[enter image description here][4]

Comment: Make sure that you have enabled your place api

Comment: Than You for your reply, Yes i checked mine is enabled, still its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about u directly read developer [Guide](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/signup) for the keys u r so confused. I'm sure its gonna help just go through it once.

Below are the step to create places api key for Android.

1. Go to Google API console.
2. Click on the dropdown and select 'create a project'.
3. Enter Project Name.
4. now click on Navigation drawer and select API Manager.
5. Enable google places api.
6. Create Credentials Android Key.
7. Enter Key Name and then hit create.
8. Now u can use the Android key for google places api.

Now u can request for nearby places checkout [this](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search?hl=en) url.

It takes SERVER_Key

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=yourlatitude,yourlongitude&radius=5000&sensor=true&key=SERVERKEY
```

1. Click on New Credentials.
2. Select Server_key.
3. Enter IP if u want it for testing purpose otherwise leave it blank.
4. finally click on create.

now thats ur server_key. It takes sm time for google to activate the service so u may get an error "The provided API key is expired" while requesting places. Check it out after sm time and u shd be getting places response.

Comment: Than you I have already carried out the above mentioned steps, Basically what i want to get cleared out is whether i use two different keys for the manifest and the java class or the same key? I have succesfully ran google maps api using an android key, but now in case of places api do i use the same key that i generated previously or use different keys? Some forums suggest using server keys for places api and some say use browser key, also i enabled google maps api & places api in the developer console, i even tried using the same android key in the manifest and java file, didn't work

Comment: Yes i have tried running the project using a server key but still the app crashes when i try to load it, I am using Eclipse and this is the code where i referred from http://javapapers.com/android/find-places-nearby-in-google-maps-using-google-places-apiandroid-app/
, Can you help?  @kevz

Comment: Hey Thanks a lot mate, now my app is running on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

> https://developers.google.com/android/   see what you cant to create .